# Keyboard Input Filtering (Quasar Framework)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, quasar-framework

**Need for help**

I want to implement “*arabic keyboard input filtering*” use `onkeyup` and `onkeypress` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/wijananto/pgvxhume/).

```
<input type="text" 
       name="searchBox"
       value=""
       placeholder="بحث"
       size="25"
       onkeypress="if(this.value.match(/[^\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u0657\u0670\uFE70-\uFEFC]/)) this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u0657\u0670\uFE70-\uFEFC]/g,'')"
       onkeyup="if(this.value.match(/[^\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u0657\u0670\uFE70-\uFEFC]/)) this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u0657\u0670\uFE70-\uFEFC]/g,'')"
       style="direction: rtl; width: 100px;">
```

How to re-implement “*arabic keyboard input filtering*” in the [Quasar-Framework](http://quasar-framework.org/) component [q-search](http://quasar-framework.org/components/search.html)?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<q-search v-model="value" name="searchBox" placeholder="بحث"  oninput="if(this.value && this.value.match(/[^\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u0657\u0670\uFE70-\uFEFC]/)) this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u0657\u0670\uFE70-\uFEFC]/g,'')" onkeyup="if(this.value && this.value.match(/[^\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u0657\u0670\uFE70-\uFEFC]/)) this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\u0621-\u063A\u0640-\u0657\u0670\uFE70-\uFEFC]/g,'')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted some time ago.
I am going to answer for rv1+ in case others should stumble across this.
I just implemented a codepen for lazy/filtering.
You can find it here: https://codepen.io/Hawkeye64/pen/abbVqdo

The relevant area of concern is what to do in the `filterFn` as found below:

```js
    async filterFn (val, update, abort) {
      // call abort() at any time if you can't retrieve data somehow
      if (this.users.length === 0) {
        // if there is no data, fetch and cache it so it can be filtered
        await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
          .then(response => {
            this.users = response.data
          })
      }
      if (val === '') {
        update(() => {
          this.options = this.users.map(user => user.username)
        })
      } else if (this.users.length === 0) {
        update(() => {
          this.options = []
        })
      } else {
        update(() => {
          this.options = this.users
            .map(user => user.username)
            .filter(name => {
              return name && name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) !== -1
          })
        })
      }
    },
```